# Include PHP file inside a DIV using Jquery & AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is that I need to include a PHP file inside a DIV when a button is pressed without the page reloading.

There is even more explanation in the 'Jsfiddle' file.

Below is an included Jsfiddle document.

http://jsfiddle.net/jjygp/5/

Thanks for your time. I am more than happy to provide any information upon request.

Answer (score 3):

See [here for your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjygp/5/)

You had marked the change button with a name of `Change` but were trying to select it with an id of `change`. Also, you had not told jsfiddle to include jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on jsfiddle, not with my actual code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<button name="Change" id="Change">Change Div</button>
```

You are specifying a click function on an id, but no id is set on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with load() function in jquery

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side script language, which will be executed before a JavaScript script did.

Therefore, you cannot use `.load()` to execute a PHP code, however, you may try `.ajax()` to create an AJAX request to the server which can implement the PHP code.

Please see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ if you have trouble on using `.ajax()`.

Note: in `.ajax()` method, there is a setting called `beforeSend`, which "can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent". Hope this method helps you in any way.

Then, your JavaScript code will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Change").click(function(){
    //doing AJAX request
    $.ajax({
      url:"include/start10.php",
      beforeSend:function(){
        $('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow');
      },
      success:function(data){
        // do something with the return data if you have
        // the return data could be a plain-text, or HTML, or JSON, or JSONP, depends on your needs, if you do ha

        $('#myDiv').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    });    
  });
});
```

Comment: Would this work with a full on PHP page? I wanted this function to work like a "PHP include" works.

Comment: @tushar747 sorry for so late response. Javascript is a entirely different language compared to PHP, but they can work together in a HTML document like: `  
  <html><body><?php echo 'here is the PHP code'; ?><script>alert('here is the JS code')</script></body></html>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include PHP file with AJAX, but instead the response of the AJAX server-side script, which is the PHP (which has the same effect).

Loading...

The JS file (code):

```
function ajaxalizeDiv()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/path/to/the/php/you/want/to/include",
        data: {
            // Anything in json format you may want to include
            id: myvarwithid, // descriptive example
            action: "read" // descriptive example
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: onAjax
    });
}

function onAjax(res)
{
    if(!res || !res.text)
        return;

    $("#mydiv").html(res.text);
}
```

And here goes the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $id = (int) @$_GET['id']; // same as in data part of ajax query request
    $action = @$_GET['action']; // same as in data part of ajax query request

    $text = '<a href="/index.php?id=' . $id . '&action=' . $action . '">click me</a>';

    // Note this is short example you may want to echo instead of die
    // You may use not JSON, but raw text. However, JSON is more human-friendy (readable)
    // and easy to maintain.
    // Note also the array keys are used in the onAjax function form res (response).
    die(json_encode(array('text' => $text /* and anything else you want */)));
?>
```